# I've finished Seiklus, but I'm still a little confused. Does the ending mean anything?

Tags: seiklus

**Warning: Spoilers ahead!** Don't read if you don't want the (kind of confusing) ending ruined!

> Okay, so I've finished Seiklus. I reached 100% completion, retrieved all the "cheese wedges of power", and assembled them in the "moon temple". Annnnd, the credits roll. I guess I won, but I was kind of expecting more.

Am I a clod missing some obvious hidden symbolism, or is the ending supposed to be vague and open-ended?

Comment: +1, Seiklus is fantastic in every way and more people should play it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the ending is supposed to be vague, as the game is not so much about winning as it is about being in a wonderful, mysterious place. Once you find the floaty things you get back to the girl, and the pie pieces are extra treasure to encourage further exploration. In my opinion, Seiklus is of a rare breed of game where it is about the journey, not the destination.

Comment: Yes, it does seem like a enjoyable journey best taken at face value, for the most part.